# HDS/HIM for 2009 Acura TL

Tags: acura

Does anyone know of a way of performing a "PGM-FI INSPECTION -> ALL INJECTORS STOP" procedure on a Honda/Acura car with a low cost HDS/HIM tool?

Thank you.